# DRF view for relational data

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model `Classroom` -

```py
class Classroom(models.Model):
    CODE_LEN = 16
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=CODE_LEN, unique=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), related_name='enrolled_classrooms')
```

And, a model `Announcement` -

```py
class Announcement(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

On this endpoint - `classes/<str:code>/announcements` I want to return all the announcements for a particular classroom

This is how I am doing it -

```py
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def announcements(request, code):
    classroom = get_object_or_404(Classroom, code=code)
    user = request.user
    
    #only teachers and students can post an announcement
    if not (user == classroom.teacher or classroom in user.enrolled_classrooms.all()):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = AnnouncementSerializer(classroom.announcement_set.all(), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        request.data.update({"classroom": classroom.id})
        request.data.update({"author": user.id})

        serializer = NewAnnouncementSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(AnnouncementSerializer(serializer.instance).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

These are the serializers -

```py
class AnnouncementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Announcement
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'author', 'created_at', 'edited_at')


class NewAnnouncementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Announcement
        fields = ('text', 'classroom', 'author')
```

I want to use custom permission to check if a user is one of teacher or student, so I want to create the view using drf `generics`. But, I don't know how to make a generic view for such relational data.

Answer (score 1):

In your Announcement model add related_name-

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="xyz)
```

Now in your serializer :
First, define announcement_serializer and then define Classroom_serializer as -

```
class ClassRoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    xyz=announcement_serializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Classroom
        fields = ('id', 'xyz')
```

Now if you visit localhost:8000/classes. you will get all the announcement related to that classroom.

Hope this helps and you can change it according to your needs.

EDIT - A different approach based on queryparams.

```
if request.method == 'GET':

    classroomId = request.GET.get('classroom_id')
    if classroomId is not None:
        queryset = announcement.objects.filter(classroom=classroomId)
    else:
        queryset = announcement.objects.all()
    serializer = AnnouncementSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now there will same url but you can pass params to get your desired results

1. **localhost:8000/announcement** will show all the announcement
2. **localhost:8000/announcement/?classroom_id=some_id_value** will show you filtered announcement based on the classroom Id which you pass here.

Comment: I have other models like `Assignment` that are related to `Classroom` just like `Announcement`. So, to get announcements of a class I need to use the endpoint - `classes/<str:code>/announcements` and to get assignments of a class I need to use the endpoint - `classes/<str:code>/assignments` .
I want to access announcements and assignments separately, so I cannot add them to my `ClassroomSerializer`

Comment: Why don't you create a new serializer called **classroomWithAnnouncement_serializer** and a different view as **classroomWithAnnouncement_viewset** and map this to url **localhost:8000/classRoomWithAnnouncment**.  sometimes you have to play around in a systematic manner to get the desired result.

Comment: create two more urls, one for  classRoomWithAssignment (with different viewset and linked serializer (Assignment serializer)  and the other only for Classroom without any linked serializer. So you will get three urls and three different datasets.

Comment: check the edited answer, you can also use queryparams